# How can I section equation for line in polar coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was able to draw the two circles but I need to plot the two lines `$\theta = -\frac{\pi}{3}$ and $\theta = \frac{5\pi}{6}$` so I can have region of all points.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
  \begin{polaraxis}[xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,very thick]
    \addplot[name path=r1, domain=0:360,samples=300,blue] {2} node[pos=0.35, above]{$r_1$};
    \addplot[name path=r2, domain=0:360,samples=300,violet] {3} node[pos=0.2, below]{$r_2$};
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are polar axes so you could add parametric plots like

```
\addplot[domain=2:3,red,samples=2] (-60,x);
\addplot[domain=2:3,cyan,samples=2] (150,x);
```

Please note that you do not use the named paths in the code (but I keep the `name path` keys).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween,polar}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
  \begin{polaraxis}[xticklabel=$\pgfmathprintnumber{\tick}^\circ$,very thick]
    \addplot[name path=r1, domain=0:360,samples=300,blue] {2} node[pos=0.35, above]{$r_1$};
    \addplot[name path=r2, domain=0:360,samples=300,violet] {3} node[pos=0.2, below]{$r_2$};
    \addplot[domain=2:3,red,samples=2] (-60,x);
    \addplot[domain=2:3,cyan,samples=2] (150,x);    
  \end{polaraxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]